# move_uploaded_file not working

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm uploading files via JS and storing the temp path in the session.
Than i use the following code to move the files.

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_SESSION['temp_img'][$key]['path'], $dest.$bigimg)){
```

`$dest` and `$bigimg` are defined earlier in the script with the id from the database.

Any Ideas or alternatives ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MANCHUCK's answer was close but not quite there. You must call `move_uploaded_file` within the script where the file was uploaded. You cannot do what you're doing, that is, "storing temp path in the session" because that path is only valid for one request.

From the PHP manual:

> The file will be deleted from the
>   temporary directory **at the end of the
>   request** if it has not been moved away
>   or renamed.

(Emphasis mine)

Answer (score 1):

move_uploaded_file checks that a file has been uploaded to that page.  You are actually uploading the file to a different PHP script then storing in a session.  Instead of using move_upload_file use rename.

Comment: That shows the issue however it still won't work. If he doesn't call `move_uploaded_file` before the request finishes the file will be deleted.

Answer (score -2):

What is the output of $_SESSION['temp_img'][$key]['path'], also do you have permission to write to the web directory your placing the files.  You may need to set it to 777 for some hosts to allow the webserver to write there.

Comment: since he is uploaded to a different script, move_uploaded_file is failing since no file was actually posted to that script

Comment: /tmp/phpbvWPqW -the output from session
and the permissions are set